# Is it possible to use PyCharm debug interface with pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

The python script is executed on a remote machine. Due to certain security policies I cannot use the built-in PyCharm debugger remotely, but pdb works fine. Is there any way to somehow view the variables (DataFrames, arrays) in the built-in PyCharm's viewers instead of the default pdb console output?

Comment: It is not possible, unfortunately. Though you can try the "Python Debug Server" PyCharm feature if it doesn't violate your security policy https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config